# Need help adding custom icon marker and popup that loads from a geojson source

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js

I have a system whereby each individual coordinate will have their respective icon.

Initially I tried the following to add the marker with individual icon image and it works. But I realised that previously created marker coordinate is still present despite a change in location. Example A was at X at 10.10PM. At 10.20PM A moved to Y. The map created a new marker instead of overwriting the old one.

```js
var geojsonurl = '****.php';
  var geojson;


  var x = function (){
  $.ajax({
    url: geojsonurl,
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data) {
        geojson = data;
        geojson.features.forEach(function(marker) {
            // create a DOM element for the marker
            var el = document.createElement('div');
            el.className = 'marker';
            el.style.backgroundImage = 'url(http://****images/avatars/' + marker.properties.imagename+ '.png';
            el.style.width = marker.properties.iconSize[0] + 'px';
            el.style.height = marker.properties.iconSize[1] + 'px';
        
            el.addEventListener('click', function() {
                window.alert(marker.properties.message);
            });
                // add marker to map
                new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
                .setLngLat(marker.geometry.coordinates)
                .addTo(map);
                
         
        
        });
   
        
    }, error: function () {
        
    }
});
};
```

I have also tried using the following which resolved the problem then I encountered in the above code. But now I'm stuck at retrieving the respective Icon image and the necessary information (e.g. Popup etc.)

```js
var url = '****.php';
map.on('load', function () {
    window.setInterval(function() {
        map.getSource('drone').setData(url);
    }, 2000);




    map.addSource('drone', { type: 'geojson', data: url });
    
    map.addLayer({
        "id": "drone",
        "type": "symbol",
        "source": "drone",
        "layout": {
            "icon-image": 
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: The respective icons are from a php file that has the attribute called image name.

Answer (score 0):

You need to decide whether you're using markers or symbol layers. Markers are more flexible in appearance, giving you full access to HTML, so it's easy to display whatever image you want. Symbol layers are easier to link directly to the data, and interact better with other layers (hiding instead of colliding with each other, for instance.)

Let's go with markers for now. Your problem with the first approach is you're creating new markers each time, you're not removing the old ones, or updating them. If you want to update them, you'll need to store them first:

```
  var geojson;
  var markers = [];

  // ...

  geojson.features.forEach(function(marker, markerIndex) {
        // Check if we have made this marker before
        var marker = markers[markerIndex];
        var el = marker && marker.getElement();
        if (!el) {
            // create a DOM element for the marker
            el = document.createElement('div');

            el.addEventListener('click', function() {
                // we refer to geojson.features[] rather than this particular marker, so it will update properly when the data changes

window.alert(geojson.features[markerIndex].properties.message);
            });

            // add marker to map
            markers[markerIndex] = new mapboxgl.Marker(el);
            marker
                .setLngLat(marker.geometry.coordinates)
                .addTo(map);

        }

        // Either update existing marker, or set up new one, it's the same.
        el.className = 'marker';
        el.style.backgroundImage = 'url(http://****images/avatars/' + marker.properties.imagename+ '.png';
        el.style.width = marker.properties.iconSize[0] + 'px';
        el.style.height = marker.properties.iconSize[1] + 'px';

        marker.setLngLat(marker.geometry.coordinates);

    // ....
```

If you go with symbol layers, it's probably simpler. You just need to load your custom images once at the start:

```
map.loadImage('image1', 'http://****images/avatars/image1.png';
```

then:

```
map.addLayer({
        "id": "drone",
        "type": "symbol",
        "source": "drone",
        "layout": {
            "icon-image": "image1"
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you I will give it a try. Currently I decided to use mapbox JS instead of GL since it suits my needs and the documentation seems to be user friendly.